# Retrieving Stripe Session Object on a Connected Account in Node

Tags: stripe-payments

Looking for advice on how to retrieve a checkout [session object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions) in Stripe associated with a [connected account](https://stripe.com/connect) using Node.

Retrieving a session object is simple for sessions tied to my own account:

```
var stripeSession = {STRIPE_SESSION_ID}
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(stripeSession);
```

But I'm not seeing any documentation how how to retrieve a session associated with a connected account. I think the solution has something to do with this: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication, but unclear on how to re-structure the retrieve method.

For instance, trying:

```
    // Session ID
    var stripeSession = req.query.stripesession;

    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(
        {session: stripeSession},
        {stripeAccount: "ACCOUNT_VALUE"});
```

Is yielding an error of  "Argument "session" must be a string, but got: [object Object]"

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it was simple...

```
// Find the stripe session
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(
  "SESSION_ID", {stripeAccount: "ACCOUNT_ID"}
);
```